# String permutation with duplicate characters

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I have string "0011" and want all of the combinations without duplicate.
that's means I want a string with a combination of two '0' and two '1';
for example : [0011,0101,0110,1001,1010,1100]

I tried with this and the result is exactly what i need.

```
private void permutation(String result, String str, HashSet hashset) {
        if (str.length()==0 && !hashSet.contains(result)){
            System.out.println(result);
            hashSet.add(result);
            return;
        }
        IntStream.range(0,str.length()).forEach(pos->permutation(result+ str.charAt(pos), str.substring(0, pos) + str.substring(pos+1),hashset));
    }
```

if i remove HashSet, this code will produce 24 results instead of 6 results.

but the time complexity of this code is O(n!).
how to avoid it to create a duplicate string and reduce the time complexity?

Comment: The time complexity is worst case *O(n!)*, since there can be *n!* results in the list, and one can not generate a list of *k* elements in less than *k* steps. One can of course in some cases reduce the time complexity. For example here if the character set is limited.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Even so, it will still generally be at least exponential in the length of the string.  For example if not more than half the characters are the same then there are always at least `2^n / (n+1)` possibilities.  (Proof: `2^n` is the sum of `n` choose `m` where `m` ranges over `0..n`.  No coefficient exceeds the middle one, and therefore that one must be at least `2^n / (n+1)`.)

Comment: @btilly: not per se, for example the family of *n-1* `1`s and 1 `0`s has always `n` permutations. So some "families" can indeed be better. But the point is that in general, it can not be improved, and indeed for cases with half `1`s and half `0`s, it still scales exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this can be faster than n! even on small n
The idea is to count how many bits we need should be in resulting item and 
iterate through all posible values and filter only those than have same number of bits. It will work similar amount of time with only one 1 and for 50%/50% of 0 and 1

```js
function bitCount(n) {
        n = n - ((n >> 1) & 0x55555555)
        n = (n & 0x33333333) + ((n >> 2) & 0x33333333)
        return ((n + (n >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24
    }
    function perm(inp) {
        const bitString = 2;
        const len = inp.length;
        const target = bitCount(parseInt(inp, bitString));
        const min = (Math.pow(target, bitString) - 1);
        const max = min << (len - target);
        const result = [];
        for (let i = min; i < max + 1; i++) {
            if (bitCount(i) === target) {
                result.push(i.toString(bitString).padStart(len, '0'));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
     const inp = '0011';
     const res = perm(inp);
     console.log('result',res);
```

P.s. My first idea was probably faster than upper code. But upper is easier to implement

first idea was to convert string to int
and use bitwise left shift but only for one digit every time. it still depends on n. and can be larger or smaller than upper solution. but bitwise shift is faster itself.

```
example 
const input = '0011'
const len = input.length;

step1: calc number of bits = 2;
then generate first element = 3(Dec) is = '0011' in bin
step2 move last from the right bit one position left with << operator: '0101'
step3 move again: '1001'
step4: we are reached `len` so use next bit:100'1' : '1010'
step5: repeat:'1100'
step6: move initial 3 << 1: '0110'
repeat above steps: '1010'
step8: '1100'
it will generate duplicates so probably can be improved
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The worst case time complexity cannot be improved because there can be no duplicates in a string. However, in case of a multi-set, we could prune a lot of sub-trees to prevent duplicates.

The key idea is to permute the string using traditional backtracking algorithm but prevent swapping if the character has been previously swapped to prevent duplicates.

Here is a C++ code snippet that prevents duplicates and doesn't use any memory for lookup.

```
bool shouldSwap(const string& str, size_t start, size_t index) {
  for (auto i = start; i < index; ++i) {
    if (str[i] == str[index])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void permute(string& str, size_t index)
{
  if (index >= str.size()) {
    cout << str << endl;;
    return;
  }

  for (size_t i = index; i < str.size(); ++i) {
    if(shouldSwap(str, index, i)) {
      swap(str[index], str[i]);
      permute(str, index + 1);
      swap(str[index], str[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Running [demo](https://ideone.com/h4MOi9). Also refer to SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206047/permutations-of-a-string-with-no-duplicates) and [Distinct permutations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-permutations-string-set-2/) for more references.

Also, note that the time complexity of this solution is **O(n<sup>2</sup> n!)**

- O(n) for printing a string
- O(n) for iterating over the string to generate swaps and recurrence.
- O(n!) possible states for the number of permutations.